# Leer excel con selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, java-8, selenium-webdriver

estoy intentado mejorar el código y una de las mejoras es mostrar todas las filas y columnas menos la primera fila de un excel.
Lo que me está funcionando es indicar cuantas filas y columnas tienen datos en un excel para que me permita leérmelas.
aquí os dejo el código

```
public static  List<String> listaDatos = new ArrayList<>();
//Padre con elementos encapsulados
public static List<Data> LISTA_DATOS = new ArrayList<>();

public Data data(String hoja, int n) throws IOException {
    //ruta del excel
    XSSFWorkbook samplexlsx = new XSSFWorkbook("dataloader/excel.xlsx");
    //nombremos la hoja
    XSSFSheet sheet1 = samplexlsx.getSheet(hoja);
    //indicamos las posiciones del excel
    int rowCount = sheet1.getLastRowNum() + sheet1.getFirstRowNum();
    for (int fila = 0; fila < 3; fila++){
       String dato = "";

        for (int columna = 0; columna < 4; columna++){
            try {
               dato += sheet1.getRow(fila).getCell(columna).getNumericCellValue() + ";";
              //  System.out.print(sheet1.getRow(fila).getCell(columna).getNumericCellValue()+ ";");
            } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                dato += sheet1.getRow(fila).getCell(columna).getStringCellValue() + ";";
              //  System.out.print(sheet1.getRow(fila).getCell(columna).getStringCellValue()+ ";");
            }
        }
        //añadimos los datos en una lista
        listaDatos.add(dato);
    }
    //eliminamos la posición de Arraylist
    listaDatos.remove(0);
    //indicamos los datos que van a salir
    for ( String data : listaDatos){
  
        String [] datosPersonales = data.split(";");
        String url =  datosPersonales[0];
        String firstName =  datosPersonales[1];
        String lastName = datosPersonales[2];
        String id = datosPersonales[3];         
       
        Data p = new Data(url,firstName, lastName, Integer.parseInt(id));
        // ,Integer.parseInt(id));
        
      
        LISTA_DATOS.add(p);
        
    }
    
    return LISTA_DATOS.get(n);
   
   
}
```

El objeto **Data**, esta indicando los valores que debe mostrar
Gracias por poder ayudarme, un saludo!
He modificado el recorrido del excel pero me da este error

```
int rowCount = sheet1.getLastRowNum()-sheet1.getFirstRowNum();
for (int i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
            String dato = "";
            Row row = sheet1.getRow(i);
            //int total = 0;
            //ArrayList<Integer> blank =new ArrayList<Integer>();
            //int type=-1;
            String s = null;
            for(int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++){
                try {
                    System.out.print(row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue()+"|| ");
                       dato += sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(j).getNumericCellValue() + ";";
                      // System.out.print(sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(j).getNumericCellValue()+ ";");
                    } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                        dato += sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue() + ";";
                      //  System.out.print(sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue()+ ";");
                    }
            }
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 2 out of bounds for length 0
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:266)
at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:359)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:427)
at excel.test.Ejemplo2.findRealRows(Ejemplo2.java:78)
at excel.test.Ejemplo2.main(Ejemplo2.java:17)

Comment: Estoy diciendo añadiendo unos parámetros nuevos en el ciclo para recorrer toda la lista

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado!
debemos añadir un try al principio, usando el código que he comentado antes.
así sería:

```
public static Data findRealRows(String hoja, int n)  {
        //ruta del excel
                XSSFWorkbook samplexlsx;
                try {
                    samplexlsx = new XSSFWorkbook("dataloader/excel.xlsx");
                    //nombremos la hoja
                    XSSFSheet sheet1 = samplexlsx.getSheet(hoja);
            //int row_real = 0;
            // int rows = sheet1.getPhysicalNumberOfRows (); // Aquí hay errores en las estadísticas físicas del número de fila,
             int rowCount = sheet1.getLastRowNum()-sheet1.getFirstRowNum();
            //int size = flag.length;
            try {
         
         
            for (int i =1; i < rowCount; i++) {
                String dato = "";
                Row row = sheet1.getRow(i);
                //int total = 0;
                //ArrayList<Integer> blank =new ArrayList<Integer>();
                //int type=-1;
                String s = null;
                for(int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++){
                    try {
                        //System.out.print(row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue()+"|| ");
                           dato += row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue()+ ";";
                          // System.out.print(sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(j).getNumericCellValue()+ ";");
                        } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
                            dato += row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue() + ";";
                          //  System.out.print(sheet1.getRow(i).getCell(j).getStringCellValue()+ ";");
                        }
                }
                // System.out.println (s + "Me");
                // System.out.println( "listad "+ listaDatos.add(dato));
                 listaDatos.add(dato);
        
         
            }
            
                
        //   System.out.println("new "+ LISTA_DATOS.get(1).getNombre());
            // return LISTA_DATOS.get(1);
            }
            
            catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // lanzar una nueva BusinessException ("Excepción de formato de Excel, compruebe si faltan datos en formato Excel, filas de datos no válidas");
            }
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                
                  // listaDatos.remove(0);
                 for ( String data : listaDatos){
                      
                        String [] datosPersonales = data.split(";");
                        String url =  datosPersonales[0];
                        String firstName =  datosPersonales[1];
                        String lastName = datosPersonales[2];
                        String id = datosPersonales[3];         
                       
                        Data p = new Data(url,firstName, lastName, Integer.parseInt(id));
                        // ,Integer.parseInt(id));
                     //   System.out.println("new  "+data.toString());
                      
                        LISTA_DATOS.add(p);
                        
                    }
                 //System.out.println(LISTA_DATOS.get(1).getNombre());
        return LISTA_DATOS.get(n);
          
    }
```